# Will hair restart growing after a dietary protein deficiency is fixed?

Tags: hair

The [Livestrong article: *How Much Protein to Prevent Hair Loss*](http://www.livestrong.com/article/441073-how-much-protein-to-prevent-hair-loss/) claims:

> Hair is made from protein. When the body does not get enough protein, it rations it by shutting down the production of non-essential protein, including hair growth. Hair loss is noticeable about two to three months after protein intake drops below requirements. **Hair growth will begin again once protein intake meets needs.**

Is there evidence that hair loss due to protein deficiency is only temporary?

Comment: Note: Self-help questions are off-topic. Please seek personal medical advice from a doctor. This claim is not that protein promotes hair regrowth generally, but that hair-loss due to protein deficiency can be remedied by fixing the dietary problems.

Comment: @Oddthinking Fine. I was trying to make it more specific to my case. Will take care in future to keep it generic.

Comment: If the follicle is gone there's no amount of protein intake that can get it back.

Comment: @MichaelBay - I'm pretty sure I hate you with every molecule of my follicle-challenge noggin.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet LOL, I feel your pain... The point being there are two main cause for alopecia (hair loss): Genetics and protein deficient diets. Nothing can be done regarding the former. Regarding the latter, which symptom is more hair thinning than actually hair loss, changing the diet can at most slow down the inevitable. When both causes are present it's a recipe for disaster!

Comment: @MichaelBay - I need to get my "uni-hair" theory published so it would be notable enough to get challenged on this site: body and head hair is really a set of very long-interconnected hairs that emerge from both ends.  As gravity naturally pulls downward on it, it emerges more from the body while receding from the head as males age.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - Actually, men don't stop growing hair at all, when they go bald.  The hair just grows down through the brain and out the nose.